# How to make a snapshot from a scrolled ScrollView?

Tags: android, view, snapshot

is only using draw(Canvas) method for a ScrollView that is currently scrolled down, sufficient for making snapshot?

code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scrollView.getWidth(), scrollView.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
scrollView.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: Is it working at the moment?

Comment: It makes a blank bitmap now.

Comment: Does the scrollview holds any view or is it blank? Post your code and layout please.